# How to have scrapy iterate over archive using url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to have a scrapy spider crawl through several pages in an archive, with the goal of opening each individual link and scraping the contents of the linked page. I'm running into some random HTTP 500 errors, which I am trying to skip by simply doing a try-except to skip over those pages returning 500 errors.

The first part of the parse function iterates over the hrefs in the archive page for the pages to scrape using the parse_art function. The second part is to find the next page in the archive and follow through to that page to continue crawling.

I'm trying to change the program to iterate over an initial URL, but can't seem to get it right. Any help would be appreciated.

Running scrapy on Python 3.7.

```
import scrapy
url_number = 1

class SpiderOne(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    start_urls = ["http://www.page2bscraped.com/archive?page=%d" % url_number]

    #Parses over the archive page
    def parse(self, response):
        global url_number
        for href in response.xpath(".//a/@href"):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_art)

        for href in response.xpath(start_url):
            yield response.follow(start_url, self.parse)
            url_number += 1

    #Parses page contents                              
    def parse_art(self, response):
    #code goes here
```

I'm trying to make it so that the spider crawls through the archive by utilizing the url and simply adding 1 to the current archive number, rather than relying on the (unreliable) "Next Page" Xpath.

Comment: adding value to `url_number` can't change value in url. It doesn't work this way. You have to use again `"http://www.page2bscraped.com/archive?page=%d" % url_number` to create new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing value `url_number` can't change value in `url`.

You have to generate full url again

```
def parse(self, response):
    global url_number

    for href in response.xpath(".//a/@href"):
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse_art)

    url_number += 1
    url = "http://www.page2bscraped.com/archive?page=%d" % url_number

    yield response.follow(url, self.parse)
```